# How to call initialization function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$main(function(){
    org.mathdox.formulaeditor.FormulaEditor = $extend(Object, {

       textarea : null,
       canvas : null,
       presentation : null,
       cursor : null,

       initialize : function(textarea, canvas) {...},

       other functions...
    }
```

I am having trouble calling the initialize function. Is there a certain scope for the function? Can I only call it inside that main function? Can I call it in external JavaScript files?

```
$('#fe_reset').click(function () {
    $('#divTextArea').remove(); 
    var textareadiv = document.createElement('div');
    textareadiv.className = 'formula_editor_textarea';
    textareadiv.id = 'divTextArea';
    var thetextarea = document.createElement('textarea');
    thetextarea.className = 'mathdoxformula';
    thetextarea.id = 'formula1'; 
    thetextarea.style.rows = '10';
    thetextarea.style.cols = '80';
    textareadiv.appendChild(thetextarea);
    document.getElementById('formula_editor_container').insertBefore(textareadiv, document.getElementById('fe_cancel'));

        initialize(thetextarea); // CAN I NOT CALL IT LIKE THIS?

    $('#fe_save').css({'cursor': 'default', 'opacity': '0.55'}).attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

Comment: How are you trying to call it, and from where?

Comment: Assuming you meant `$.extend`, can't you just call `org.mathdox.formulaeditor.FormulaEditor.initialize()`

Comment: can you post the code where you attempt to call it and where you create the instance of FormulaEditor

Comment: I guess I have to explain the file structure. My main HTML references two JavaScript files (main.js and formula_editor.js in its head tag. The purpose of main.js is to addScript() another JS file called FEconcatenation.js. The code above is in FEconcatenation.js. Where I am calling it is in formula_editor.js. I created a new textarea and I am trying to initialize it simply by using `initialize(newTextArea)`

Comment: Would I have to create an instance of FormulaEditor inside the formula_editor.js file?

Comment: Just curious, what is $main()?